# Carrierwave, Fog, Amazon S3, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get Carrierwave to work with my Amazon S3 bucket, but I'm a bit down on my luck. In my `config/initializers` folder, I have a file called, `carrierwave.rb`. This file contains the following:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']
  config.fog_public     = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

I am using the gem `figaro` as a mechanism for housing my environment configuration variables. Inside of the `application.yml`, I am defining the `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']` , `ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']`, and `ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']`.

These three variables seem to be populating properly. Using an FTP program, I am able to connect to my amazon s3 instance, using the access key and secret access keys that I have defined in the `application.yml` file. I have triple checked that my **public** and **secret** keys are correct.

When trying to perform an upload in my Rails application, I receive an error stating that:

```
Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) response => #<Excon::Response:0x007fb29a862ac8 
@data={:body=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><
Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

To remedy this, I have also tried to:

1. Create a new Amazon S3 bucket
2. Manually placing the access_key_id / secret_access_key / fog_directory in the configuration file.

Neither of these two options seem to be working. When I created a new S3 bucket and specified it in the `config.fog_directory`, I received the same error.

When I manually typed the keys and bucket name in the `carrierwave.rb` file, I still received the same error.

I've tried searching the web a bit for an answer, but most of the answers seem to be that a user mistakenly typed in the wrong access key or secret key. I do not believe that this is the case here, as I've copied and pasted the keys directly into the `carrierwave.rb` file from my S3 Management Console on Amazon.

If anyone has any insight or things that you would like me to try, please feel free to leave a comment. If you need any more information, please let me know and I will post it here. My application is a Rails 4 app, with the following gems:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog', github: 'fog/fog'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'figaro'
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: A couple of additions:

I just now tried creating a new set of keys and once again copy + pasted the keys into my `carrierwave.rb` file. I'm still receiving the same error. My file now reads as follows:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => "***********",
      :aws_secret_access_key  => "***********"
  }

  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  config.fog_directory  = 'soawsthree'
  config.fog_public     = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

--

Response from the S3 Bucket. Note- the public access key listed below is correct. Not sure where the secret access key is being passed in?:

```
Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) response => #<Excon::Response:0x007fc6e3997008 @data={:body=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 70 6e 67 0a 46 72 69 2c 20 31 31 20 4f 63 74 20 32 30 31 33 20 30 34 3a 31 30 3a 34 31 20 2b 30 30 30 30 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 2f 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 70 68 6f 74 6f 2f 70 69 63 2f 33 2f 74 6f 75 63 68 2e 70 6e 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>22E53DA9E453D05E</RequestId><HostId>ccNccOFV+iJa3/BM9RiwAqEwmJhr1KIMvmFm0EjhrBGkN4hwMWOuRF7qH5diDYd3</HostId><SignatureProvided>hiogXz0b65S/bOSWKvca7hyXzYI=</SignatureProvided><StringToSign>PUT\n\nimage/png\nFri, 11 Oct 2013 04:10:41 +0000\nx-amz-acl:public-read\n/uploads/photo/pic/3/touch.png</StringToSign><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIKNIDTDI2WI7RPNA</AWSAccessKeyId></Error>", :headers=>{"x-amz-request-id"=>"22E53DA9E453D05E", "x-amz-id-2"=>"ccNccOFV+iJa3/BM9RiwAqEwmJhr1KIMvmFm0EjhrBGkN4hwMWOuRF7qH5diDYd3", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Fri, 11 Oct 2013 04:10:34 GMT", "nnCoection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, :status=>403, :remote_ip=>"72.21.195.65"}, @body="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 70 6e 67 0a 46 72 69 2c 20 31 31 20 4f 63 74 20 32 30 31 33 20 30 34 3a 31 30 3a 34 31 20 2b 30 30 30 30 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 2f 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 70 68 6f 74 6f 2f 70 69 63 2f 33 2f 74 6f 75 63 68 2e 70 6e 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>22E53DA9E453D05E</RequestId><HostId>ccNccOFV+iJa3/BM9RiwAqEwmJhr1KIMvmFm0EjhrBGkN4hwMWOuRF7qH5diDYd3</HostId><SignatureProvided>hiogXz0b65S/bOSWKvca7hyXzYI=</SignatureProvided><StringToSign>PUT\n\nimage/png\nFri, 11 Oct 2013 04:10:41 +0000\nx-amz-acl:public-read\n/uploads/photo/pic/3/touch.png</StringToSign><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIKNIDTDI2WI7RPNA</AWSAccessKeyId></Error>", @headers={"x-amz-request-id"=>"22E53DA9E453D05E", "x-amz-id-2"=>"ccNccOFV+iJa3/BM9RiwAqEwmJhr1KIMvmFm0EjhrBGkN4hwMWOuRF7qH5diDYd3", "Content-Type"=>"application/xml", "Transfer-Encoding"=>"chunked", "Date"=>"Fri, 11 Oct 2013 04:10:34 GMT", "nnCoection"=>"close", "Server"=>"AmazonS3"}, @status=403, @remote_ip="72.21.195.65">
```

Comment: Any chance there are extraneous spaces? Or perhaps a URL-encoding issue with the key? Weird stuff like this might be in play.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I just now tried again with the access key and secret access key (copied and pasted directly from amazon). Still no luck on this :-( ..

Comment: Also, I should note that I am restarting my localhost server every time I make a configuration change, just to ensure that I am starting clean.

Comment: Are you able to see a log of what CarrierWave is sending to S3? I have a feeling something is lost in translation from your carrierwave.rb through the stack.

Comment: +1, I added a dump from the response of Amazon, where else can I look to see what Carrierwave is sending across? The public access key seems correct..

Comment: Well this is frustrating. Four years later and I am sitting with exactly the same issue, and your ultimate resolution was just to stop using Fog...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears as if Fog is using 'excon' in order to connect with the S3 bucket. I resolved my issue by removing fog and excon 0.27.2 . I switched over to the `carrierwave-aws` gem (using the same credentials, and everything is working as expected).

Comment: Good job getting to the heart of the matter.